# My select form returns null when updating in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm still new to laravel (5.5) and I'm having a problem when I update user records, the error is:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'department' cannot be null (SQL: update `users` set `password` = $2y$10$j5wfEZ3N7SYDzWA10hbAguY9o6jY.xk1vfUEw0mBmc0351ZHaYDiy, `department` = , `contactno` = 12345, `updated_at` = 2018-09-11 00:52:20, `isAdmin` = where `id` = 1)

recordscontroller.php

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //
    $edit_form = User::Join('office', 'users.department', '=', 'office.iso_code')->find($id);
    $records = User::all();
    $dept = Office::all();
    $result = DB::table('users')
                ->where('isBACSec','=', '1')
                ->get();

    return View('updateuser')->with('edit_form',$edit_form)->with('records',$records)->with('dept',$dept)->with('result',$result);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(UpdateDataRequest $request,$id)
{
    //
    $Record=User::find($id);
    $Record->wholename = $request->get('wholename');
    $Record->name = $request->get('name');
    $Record->contactno = $request->get('contact');
    $Record->department = $request->get('department');
    $Record->password =bcrypt($request->get('password')) ;
    $Record->department = $request->get('bacs');
    $Record->isAdmin = $request->get('usrlvl');
    $Record->save();
    return redirect()->back();
    $request->session()->flash('flash_message','Record updated successfully');
}
```

updateuserblade.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!-- registration form -->
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Update Record</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ url('/edited_data',$edit_form->id) }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('wholename') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="wholename" class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="wholename" type="text" class="form-control" name="wholename" value="{{ $edit_form->wholename }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('wholename'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('wholename') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('contact') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="contact" class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="contact" type="text" class="form-control" name="contact" value="{{ $edit_form->contactno }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('contact'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('contact') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('department') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="department" class="col-md-4 control-label" >Department</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select id="department" type="text" class="form-control" name="department" onchange="showDiv(this)" required autofocus>    
                                @foreach ($dept as $key=>$dept)
                                        <option value="{{$dept->iso_code}}" @if($edit_form->department == $dept->iso_code) selected @endif>{{$dept->office_name}}</option>
                                @endforeach               
                            </select>

                            @if ($errors->has('department'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('department') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="name" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $edit_form->name }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('userlvl') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="userlvl" class="col-md-4 control-label" >User Level</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <select id="userlvl" type="text" class="form-control" name="userlvl" autofocus>
                                <option value="" >User</option>
                                <option id="admin" style="display:none;" value = "1" @if($edit_form->isAdmin === 1)selected @endif>Admin</option>
                                <script type="text/javascript">

                                    function showDiv(elem){

                                       if(elem.value == "ICT"){
                                          document.getElementById('admin').style.display = 'block';
                                       }else{
                                          document.getElementById('admin').style.display = 'none';
                                       }
                                    }
                                </script>



                            </select>

                            @if ($errors->has('userlvl'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('userlvl') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>





                    @if ($edit_form->isBACSec == 1)
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox col-md-8">
                          <label><input name="bacs" id="bacs" type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="alert('This user is no longer the BAC Secretariat')" checked>Is BAC Secretariat?</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @elseif($result->isEmpty()) 
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox col-md-8">
                          <label><input name="bacs" id="bacs" type="checkbox" value="1">Assign as BAC Secretariat</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @endif


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Update
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- update edit edelete-->
   @include('usertable')

</div>
```

UpdateDataRequest.php

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateDataRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        //
        'wholename' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'department' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ];
}
```

}

Comment: make your column `department` allow null in your database, any field that you can with no value

Comment: but it shouldn't be null. the department column was getting it's data from the select from w/c is populated by another table. although it shows a selected option during updates it returns as null

Comment: try checking the value of each option if is not null `$dept->iso_code`

Comment: it isn't null though. guess my problem is with the controller. but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: whats the structure of your column `departement` is it int or string ?

Comment: string since department is made up of like 3 letter abbreviations @Beginner

Comment: Why do you ask @Beginner? oh by the way since you asked I was wondering why it only saves a certain number, when updating it saves on the database as 1. I don't get it but during debug it certainly returns the selected value

Comment: thats weird if it is okay to you can you include the structure of column `departement` maybe the problem is there a screen shot would do since in bellow you commented that department successfully passed its selected value `ICT`

Comment: https://ibb.co/bAOqzp screenshot @Beginner

Comment: your column is okay

Comment: Before updating :https://ibb.co/mKZDKp

Comment: after updating: https://ibb.co/jVPkX9 . either this or '1'

Comment: I fixed it it was just that I wasn't looking. Such a simple mistake.

Comment: whats the mistake? controller?

Comment: posted the answer below.

Comment: yeah it was the controller. thanks for the help and sorry for the troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `dd($request);` inside `public function update` method.

Comment: the value of the $request->get('department') comes from the select form in updateuser blade. what is the use of dd($request) by the way?

Comment: can you check is there a value for $request->get('department') ?
sorry for my explanation :). dd(value) is for debug the `value` it's like `var_dump($variable); 
exit();`
but more nicest style

Comment: +request: ParameterBag {#236 ▼
    #parameters: array:9 [▼
      "_token" => "FA0z7Z5dXmEVNwhwURSN0dmgAwPjc5zKuj9iWOFz"
      "_method" => "PATCH"
      "wholename" => "OJT"
      "contact" => "12345"
      "department" => "ICT"
      "name" => "admin1"
      "password" => "admin2"
      "password_confirmation" => "admin2"
      "userlvl" => "1"
    ]
  }

Comment: it has, it tried updating it again but my department column in the database returns "1" instead of the selected value the updated value became "1"

Comment: it isn't null though. guess my problem is with the controller. but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: what your column type for department in the database ?

Comment: i fixed it aleready. It's a disgrace. I wasn't looking :( thanks for your help though. i got to use the dd($request); function.

Answer (score 0):

on the controller:

```
$Record->department = $request->get('department');
$Record->password =bcrypt($request->get('password')) ;
$Record->department = $request->get('bacs');
```

Redundancy........
changed it to this:

```
   $Record->department = $request->get('department');
$Record->password =bcrypt($request->get('password')) ;
```

For goodness sake. Sorry for the troubles.